# UITableView in editing mode cell still selectable even when using

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that has `AllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` set to YES. Selecting multiple rows is a big part of my app, and it works great.

The problem is, that on one of my `tableView's` I don't want the user to be able to select the first 2 rows when in editing mode, so I have implemented the following:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row ==1) {
        return NO;
    }//end

    return YES;

}//end
```

This works how I thought it would, and doesn't show the red checkbox graphic or the option to re-sort the rows.  BUT, I can still select those rows that are not editable, and call the `indexPathsForSelectedRows` method and return the `indexPaths` of those rows.

How can I prevent the user COMPLETELY from being able to select those rows while in editing mode, and prevent touches on those from being returned when calling `indexPathsForSelectedRows`? Why isn't `canEditRowAtIndexPath:` doing this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to implement `– tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method and check if `tableView.editing == YES` then return `nil` for first two cells.

Something like,

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableView.editing == YES && indexPath.row < 2 ) 
       return nil;

    return indexPath;
}
```

You can also set the `selectionStyle` of these two cells as `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` in editing mode in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following code?

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
```

or

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
```

Comment: ***"Selecting multiple rows is a big part of my app, and it works great.

The problem is, that on one of my tableView's I don't want the user to be able to select the first 2 rows when in editing mode,"***

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I misunderstood question. Thanks for letting me know.